# Difficult sentence from a grammar dictionary

Tags: translation, sentence

For the 且つ・かつ point in the Dictionnary of Advanced Japanese Grammar, there is the following sentence.

当社は、個人情報を取り扱うにあたり、個人情報保護法はじめ適用される諸法令、規範遵守を徹底し、適切且つ慎重に管理いたします。
The given translation is : *At our company, when we handle personal information, we thoroughly observe the applicable laws and regulations, including the Personal Information Protection Law, and we manage the information properly and prudently.*

The sentence is relatively long, so when I read it, I split it. However, I don't fully understand how the english translation was done.

**1/ 個人情報保護法はじめ適用される諸法令**

I understand that it's 個人情報保護法 (Personal Information Protection Law) + はじめ but the 適用される諸法令 part bothers me. I only found that 諸法 means *"existing things"* and 令 *"command, order"*. But it doesn't make sense here considering the translation is *"applicable laws and regulations"*. I tried to google the term, but I didn't find an answer.

**2/規範遵守を徹底し**
Is this part translates to *"(we) thoroughly observe"* in the sentence ? If it's the case, a を particle could be added right before ?

Comment: Try breaking up the word 諸法令 differently. e.g. https://jisho.org/search/%E8%AB%B8 https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4

Comment: thank you. I tried with Jisho before but with 諸法 instead. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

1: 諸 means "several", so 諸法令 means "several laws".

2: "we thoroughly observe the regulation" would be translated as "私たちは規則(規範)を徹底的に遵守する". And it is the same meaning as 規範遵守を徹底する. 規範遵守 means 規範を遵守する(守る)こと.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I fully understand the sentence.